# Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar not working

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to use the `BottomNavigationBar` in Flutter, however it is giving me a weird error that seem to have no reference to my code and I am not able to find this error anywhere online. In fact every tutorial, page, or question I can find says to do it this way.

Here is my code from `home.dart`:

```
... Imports ...

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    HomePage(),
    CatPage(),
    SearchPage(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedTab = index;
    });
    print(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Loopt In'),
      ),
      body: _pageOptions[_selectedTab],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedTab,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            title: Text('Categories'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            title: Text('Search'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Interestingly enough when I change the `_pageOptions` array to have a `Text()` widgets instead of widgets that I made it work fine, but I don't know why and need it to work with my widgets obviously.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2257 pos 20: '_debugCurrentBuildTarget == context': is not true.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:40:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      BuildOwner.buildScope.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2257:20)
#3      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2261:12)
#4      RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:817:13)
#5      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:709:7)
#6      runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:748:7)
#7      main (file:///Users/garrettlove/Documents/learn/Flutter/loopt_in/lib/main.d<…>
```

Comment: do you have HomePage inside HomePage ?   HomePage(),
    CatPage(),
    SearchPage(),

Comment: @diegoveloper I'm not really sure what you mean. What i posted is my entire HomePage. CatPage() and SearchPage() currently only return Text() widgets

Comment: I mean, your main widget is : HomePage , then in your _pageOptions var I see  [HomePage(),
    CatPage(),
    SearchPage()] ,    why are you calling HomePage again inside HomePage ?

Comment: @diegoveloper oh I see, that’s because I want the user to be able to go back to the homepage by tapping the first item in the bottomNavigationBar()

Comment: if you put these options  : final _pageOptions = [
    CatPage(),
    SearchPage(),
  ];  does it works ? if not , what do you have inside CatPage and SearchPage?

Comment: @diegoveloper So when I do that it starts out on the catPage() instead of the homePage() and when I tap the searPage() it give me a different error: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..1, inclusive: 2`

Comment: stop the app and run again  , try with CatPage and SearchPage, does it works ?

Comment: @diegoveloper did both a full reload and fully stopped and restarted in and it does the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183436/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-garrett).

Comment: could you update your question with your code updated (and the error log also) ?

Comment: it might be caused by the non-concrete type of the page options. Maybe take a look at one of my post where I used the bottom nav here https://medium.com/@jacksonzhou666_71188/build-a-game-with-only-flutter-bottomnavigationbar-e87ce5c73bf7?source=friends_link&sk=daac837094f647bd205731343f847df0. I think the only difference is that my items is concrete.

Comment: Have you found the problem here? I've been trying the code you've provided but it seems that I'm missing some essential parts. It would be easy for the community to check your issue if you could provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one causing the issue is `HomePage()` set as a body, resulting to an error-causing loop.

```dart
final _pageOptions = [
  HomePage(), // replace this with a widget for the HomePage
  CatPage(),
  SearchPage(),
];
```

To solve the issue, replace `HomePage()` with a Widget to fill the home page screen.